# On android how do I use a USB printer supporting ESC/POS command set?

Tags: android, printing, usb

On android how do I use a USB printer supporting ESC/POS command set ?
I have found out the Epson SDK for android http://pos.epson.com/mobilesdks/index.htm but it seems to support only WIFI and BT printers. This is not my case, I have to deal with USB connection only. Anyone clues are welcome.

Comment: Can you check [How to get the print from the Thermal Printer in Android?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701465/how-to-get-the-print-from-the-thermal-printer-in-android

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at Star Micronics printers, they support USB on their SDK.

Comment: Yes, did see that SDK long time ago but it seems that Star Micronics printers are about of my project's price range. Thanks for the tip anyway :)