# Print existing pdf file in android

Tags: android, pdf, printing

Hey everyone so I am trying to build a small sample printing app on android and can't seem to print an existing pdf. There is plenty of documentation on creating a custom document with the canvas but I already have the document. Basically I just want to be a able to read in a pdf document and send it as a file output stream directly to the printer to be printed. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Check out those links.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15701465/how-to-print-from-the-thermal-printer-in-android http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14530058/how-can-i-print-an-image-on-a-bluetooth-printer-in-android

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Basically I just want to be a able to read in a pdf document and send it as a file output stream directly to the printer to be printed.

That's not strictly possible, unless you find some particular printer that offers such an API for Android.

If you wish to use the Android printing framework, you will need to create a `PrintDocumentAdapter` that can handle your existing PDF file. [This sample project](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Printing/PrintManager) demonstrates [one such `PrintDocumentAdapter`](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/FINAL/Printing/PrintManager/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/print/PdfDocumentAdapter.java), though it is not general-purpose.

Comment: Thanks the sample app works great, I am a little lost on how though. I was following the example from android developers and had something like this in the onWrite method     PdfDocument.PageInfo newPage = new PdfDocument.PageInfo.Builder(pageWidth, pageHeight, i).create();
but it looks like your just opening this pdf from a file stream with in=ctxt.getAssets().open("cover.pdf"); Could this be changed to to grab a pdf from the file system ?

Comment: @DougRay: Explaining everything involved in my `PdfDocumentAdapter` takes about eight pages in [my book](https://commonsware.com/Android), and so it's too long for a Stack Overflow answer. In a nutshell, `ThreadedPrintDocumentAdapter` bundles up `onLayout()` and `onWrite()` calls into `LayoutJob` and `WriteJob` objects and puts them on a work queue for a background thread. `PdfDocumentAdapter` creates custom job subclasses that writes a canned PDF file (from `assets/`).

Comment: @_@ haha  well thanks for all the help I will check it out some more !

Comment: @DougRay: "Could this be changed to to grab a pdf from the file system ?" -- in principle, that should work fine. Change `in=ctxt.getAssets().open("cover.pdf");` to something that uses a `FileInputStream`.

Comment: I love you @CommonsWare, you helped me in this situation.

Comment: Hi @CommonsWare i can see in above comment lots fans anyways i checked your example but i'm not quite sure i want to change my all coding part but you have very good knowledge in this topic so can you help me to solve my problem here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54870164/convert-html-into-pdf-using-webview-can-not-created-multiple-pages

Comment: Please use permanent links when linking to GitHub. Correct link to PrintDocumentAdapter: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/f2ffeb687d002f4a41b52a6ef5bb2580eb6a4ed6/Printing/PrintManager/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/print/PdfDocumentAdapter.java

Comment: @TomTasche: That is not a good link either. I have updated the answer with permanent links.

Comment: The link I provided is in fact a permanent link - linking to a specific git commit. Your link points to a git tag, which is of course fine too. Thanks for updating your answer!

Comment: Is it possible to print pdf with no dialog? Just print to default settings..

Comment: @iz25: AFAIK, that is not possible, sorry.

Answer (score 24):

We can simply achieve this by creating a custom `PrintDocumentAdapter`

PdfDocumentAdapter.java

```
public class PdfDocumentAdapter extends PrintDocumentAdapter {

Context context = null;
String pathName = "";
public PdfDocumentAdapter(Context ctxt, String pathName) {
    context = ctxt;
    this.pathName = pathName;
}
@Override
public void onLayout(PrintAttributes printAttributes, PrintAttributes printAttributes1, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, LayoutResultCallback layoutResultCallback, Bundle bundle) {
    if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
        layoutResultCallback.onLayoutCancelled();
    }
    else {
        PrintDocumentInfo.Builder builder=
                new PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(" file name");
        builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
                .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
                .build();
        layoutResultCallback.onLayoutFinished(builder.build(),
                !printAttributes1.equals(printAttributes));
    }
}

@Override
public void onWrite(PageRange[] pageRanges, ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor, CancellationSignal cancellationSignal, WriteResultCallback writeResultCallback) {
    InputStream in=null;
    OutputStream out=null;
    try {
        File file = new File(pathName);
        in = new FileInputStream(file);
        out=new FileOutputStream(parcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor());

        byte[] buf=new byte[16384];
        int size;

        while ((size=in.read(buf)) >= 0
                && !cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            out.write(buf, 0, size);
        }

        if (cancellationSignal.isCanceled()) {
            writeResultCallback.onWriteCancelled();
        }
        else {
            writeResultCallback.onWriteFinished(new PageRange[] { PageRange.ALL_PAGES });
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        writeResultCallback.onWriteFailed(e.getMessage());
        Logger.logError( e);
    }
    finally {
        try {
            in.close();
            out.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            Logger.logError( e);
        }
    }
}}
```

Now call print by using `PrintManager`

```
        PrintManager printManager=(PrintManager) getActivityContext().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
    try
    {
        PrintDocumentAdapter printAdapter = new PdfDocumentAdapter(Settings.sharedPref.context,filePath );
        }
        printManager.print("Document", printAdapter,new PrintAttributes.Builder().build());
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Logger.logError(e);
    }
```

Comment: that was very helpful

Comment: @KostyaM I tried the code and I get the print interface with correct number of pages of my existing PDF but it fails to render document on the page. What can be the issue ??

Comment: Everything are good, except annotation not print to paper. Is there any solution?

Comment: thank you for this, except, are you holding a context in shared preferences? :-O

Comment: Everything works well but on clicking Save PDF it saves with 0 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

For those interested in the kotlin version of the [Karthik Bollisetti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49298355/7680523) answer here is it.

The `PdfDocumentAdapter` is re-written as this

```
class PdfDocumentAdapter(private val pathName: String) : PrintDocumentAdapter() {

override fun onLayout(
    oldAttributes: PrintAttributes?,
    newAttributes: PrintAttributes,
    cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?,
    callback: LayoutResultCallback,
    bundle: Bundle
) {
    if (cancellationSignal?.isCanceled == true) {
        callback.onLayoutCancelled()
        return
    } else {
        val builder = PrintDocumentInfo.Builder(" file name")
        builder.setContentType(PrintDocumentInfo.CONTENT_TYPE_DOCUMENT)
            .setPageCount(PrintDocumentInfo.PAGE_COUNT_UNKNOWN)
            .build()

        callback.onLayoutFinished(builder.build(), newAttributes == oldAttributes)
    }
}

override fun onWrite(
    pageRanges: Array<out PageRange>,
    destination: ParcelFileDescriptor,
    cancellationSignal: CancellationSignal?,
    callback: WriteResultCallback
) {
    try {
        // copy file from the input stream to the output stream
        FileInputStream(File(pathName)).use { inStream ->
            FileOutputStream(destination.fileDescriptor).use { outStream ->
                inStream.copyTo(outStream)
            }
        }

        if (cancellationSignal?.isCanceled == true) {
            callback.onWriteCancelled()
        } else {
            callback.onWriteFinished(arrayOf(PageRange.ALL_PAGES))
        }

    } catch (e: Exception) {
        callback.onWriteFailed(e.message)
    }
}
}
```

then call the PrintManager in your code like this

```
val printManager : PrintManager = requireContext().getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE) as PrintManager
try {
    val printAdapter = PdfDocumentAdapter(file.absolutePath)
    printManager.print("Document", printAdapter, PrintAttributes.Builder().build())
} catch (e : Exception) {
    Timber.e(e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For use cases with printers supporting ipp and pdf you can send pdfs straight to printers using my library https://github.com/gmuth/ipp-client-kotlin:

```
Kotlin:
val printer = IppPrinter(URI.create("ipp://myprinter/ipp"))
val job = printer.printJob(File("mydocument.pdf"))
job.waitForTermination()
```

No print dialog is involved.

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to print multiple PDF files to a configured printer. If I know the printer's IP address - how can I send multiple PDF files for printing?

Comment: Just call printJob() for every file you want to print. It's up to you if you want to monitor the jobs status.