# How to print PDF file contains logo and tables in android studio programatically

Tags: android, android-studio

I have created a PDF file when I clicked the view button in my app. I don't know how to print the same when I click the "Print" button in my app. I have tried by followed some links but it is not working for me.

Link which I have tried - [Print existing pdf file in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089808/print-existing-pdf-file-in-android)

The below code, which I was used to create/generate PDF file from my adapter file.

```
SampleAdapter.java 
------------------------
 private void createPdf(String id) throws FileNotFoundException, DocumentException {

        File pdfFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "pdfdemo");
        //File pdfFolder = new File(context.getFilesDir(), "pdfdemo");
        if (!pdfFolder.exists()) {
            pdfFolder.mkdirs();
            Log.e("LOG_TAG", "Pdf Directory created"+pdfFolder);
        }

        //Create time stamp
        Date date = new Date() ;
        String timeStamp = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss").format(date);

        File myFile = new File(pdfFolder +"/"+ timeStamp + ".pdf");

        OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(myFile);

        //Step 1
        Document document = new Document(PageSize.A4, 36, 36, 36, 36);

        //Step 2
        PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, output);

        //Step 3
        document.open();



        // add image
        Drawable d = context.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.na);
        BitmapDrawable bitDw = ((BitmapDrawable) d);
        Bitmap bmp = bitDw.getBitmap();
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, stream);
        Image image = null;
        try {
            image = Image.getInstance(stream.toByteArray());
            image.scaleToFit(100,100);

            // image.setAbsolutePosition( 0,180);
            image.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_LEFT);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        PdfPTable table = new PdfPTable(2);
        table.setWidthPercentage(100);
        table.setWidths(new int[]{1, 3});
        table.addCell(image);
        PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();
        Font green = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 20, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.GREEN);
        Chunk redText = new Chunk("NATIONAL AGRO FOUNDATION", green);
        Paragraph p = new Paragraph();
        p.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p.add(redText);
        cell.addElement(p);
        Font black = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 12, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text2 = new Chunk("LABORATARY SERVICES DIVISION", black);
        Paragraph p2 = new Paragraph();
        p2.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p2.add(text2);
        cell.addElement(p2);
        Font black2 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text3 = new Chunk("Tharamani, Chennai, Tamil Nadu 600113", black2);
        Paragraph p3 = new Paragraph();
        p3.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p3.add(text3);
        cell.addElement(p3);
        Font black3 = new Font(Font.FontFamily.HELVETICA, 10, Font.BOLD, BaseColor.BLACK);
        Chunk text4 = new Chunk("Phone: 044 2254 2803", black3);
        Paragraph p4 = new Paragraph();
        p4.setAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
        p4.add(text4);
        cell.addElement(p4);
```

Comment: There are several answers on that question. "I have tried by followed some links but it is not working for me" is insufficient of an explanation of what you tried and what specifically did not work. Showing us code of how you created the PDF is nice, but it is not a [mcve] of how you tried to print it.

Comment: @CommonsWare When i tried to implement my code as it is given in the link [link] (https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/FINAL/Printing/PrintManager),am getting error in this line - startService(new Intent(this, PrintJobMonitorService.class)); in my SampleAdapter.java file. I have created 3 files as in the link and when I tried to add MainActivity.jave code in my SampleAdapter.java file am getting error.

Comment: I am calling doPrint() function, when print button is clicked and the respective code is below....     
` private void doPrint() {
        WebView print=prepPrintWebView("Webpage");
        print.loadUrl("https://commonsware.com/Android");
    }
    private WebView prepPrintWebView(final String name) {
        ......
    }

    private WebView getWebView() {
        ......
    }
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    private PrintJob print(String name, ....) {
        startService(new Intent(this, PrintJobMonitorService.class));        
    }
  `

Comment: I recommend that you ask a separate Stack Overflow question, where you provide a [mcve] showing how you are printing, where you can explain **in detail** what "am getting error" means.