# Print PDF files using network printer in Android

Tags: android, pdf, android-print-manager

I am trying to print multiple PDF files using a network printer.
I already went through this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33089808/print-existing-pdf-file-in-android), but am looking for this process:

1. Application will have some configuration so that user can choose which network printer he'd like to use for printing.
2. User will fetch multiple PDF files from a remote storage (Google Drive etc.) - I will handle this separately.
3. Application will print all documents with the chosen printer - sequentially.

How can this be achieved without having the preview screen that pops up while using the Android printManager service?
Can I programmatically send to print given a printer's IP address?

Thank you!

Comment: thanks @KJ, so basically if I would like to build an Android application that will be able to print multiple PDF files on a network printer (assuming I know the printer's IP address) - is this feasible at all?